# How to enable promiscuous mode in a KVM virtual NIC?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

1. How to enable promiscuous mode on an Xubuntu 14.04.1 host?
2. How to enable promiscuous mode in a KVM virtual NIC? (using virt-manager if possible.)